Argument of type 'Number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | null | undefined'. [plugin angular-compiler]
I got the error with DecimalPipe while converting number
My code:
Service
export interface RoomList {
    roomNumber: number;
    roomType: string;
    amenities: string;
    price: number;
    photos: string;
    checkinTime: Date;
    checkoutTime: Date;
    rating: Number;
}

Component
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Room, RoomList } from './rooms';
import { CurrencyPipe, DatePipe, DecimalPipe, LowerCasePipe, NgClass, NgFor, NgIf, NgStyle } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-rooms',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [NgIf, NgFor, NgClass, NgStyle, DatePipe, CurrencyPipe, LowerCasePipe, DecimalPipe],
  templateUrl: './rooms.component.html',
  styleUrl: './rooms.component.scss'
})
export class RoomsComponent {
  hotelName = "Hilton Hotel";
  numberOfRoom = 10;
  hideRoom = false;
  rooms: Room = {
    availableRooms: 10,
    bookedRooms: 5,
    totalRooms: 20
  };

  roomList: RoomList[] = [
    {
      roomNumber: 1,
      roomType: 'Heloe',
      amenities: "HN",
      price: 5000,
      photos: './image2',
      checkinTime: new Date('11-Nov-2021'),
      checkoutTime: new Date('12-Nov-2021'),
      rating: 4.555
    },
    {
      roomNumber: 2,
      roomType: 'Donh',
      amenities: "NB",
      price: 10000,
      photos: './image2',
      checkinTime: new Date('17-Sep-2021'),
      checkoutTime: new Date('20-Sep-2021'),
      rating: 3.516
    },
    {
      roomNumber: 3,
      roomType: 'Holds',
      amenities: "DN",
      price: 200,
      photos: './image3',
      checkinTime: new Date('17-Sep-2021'),
      checkoutTime: new Date('20-Sep-2021'),
      rating: 3.99999
    },
    {
      roomNumber: 4,
      roomType: 'Bed',
      amenities: "CT",
      price: 1000,
      photos: './image4',
      checkinTime: new Date('11-Mar-2024'),
      checkoutTime: new Date('20-July-2024'),
      rating: 4.999
    }
  ];


  fnName() {

  }
  toggle() {
    this.hideRoom = !this.hideRoom;
  }
}

html
<div *ngIf="rooms.availableRooms > 0">
    Rooms List
    <!-- {{roomList}} -->
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Order</th>
            <th>Room Number</th>
            <th>Room Type</th>
            <th>Room Amenity</th>
            <th>Room Price</th>
            <th>Checkin Time</th>
            <th>Checkout Time</th>
            <th>Rating</th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let room of roomList; let i=index;" [ngClass]="i%2 ? 'even' : 'odd'">
            <td>{{i}}</td>
            <td>{{room.roomNumber}}</td>
            <td>{{room.roomType}}</td>
            <td>{{room.amenities | lowercase}}</td>
            <td>{{room.price | currency : 'INR'}}</td>
            <td>{{room.checkinTime | date:'short'}}</td>
            <td>{{room.checkoutTime | date: 'short'}}</td>
            <td>{{room.rating | number}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

I tried with this format below
<td>{{room.rating | number: '1.1-2'}}</td>

but it got error like
X [ERROR] NG9: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(value: string | number, digitsInfo?: string | undefined, locale?: string | undefined): string | null', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(value: null | undefined, digitsInfo?: string | undefined, locale?: string | undefined): null', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'null | undefined'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(value: string | number | null | undefined, digitsInfo?: string | undefined, locale?: string | undefined): string | null', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | null | undefined'. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/rooms/rooms.component.html:30:23:
      30 │             <td>{{room.rating | number: '1.1-2'}}</td>
         ╵                        ~~~~~~

  Error occurs in the template of component RoomsComponent.

    src/app/rooms/rooms.component.ts:9:15:
      9 │   templateUrl: './rooms.component.html',
        ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Number (starting with a capital letter) is a special built-in type. It is only necessary in very rare cases. In your case, you need to use the lowercase number type. See the TypeScript documentation.

The error you are encountering is due to the fact that the DecimalPipe (or number pipe) expects a value of type string, number, null, or undefined, but your RoomList interface is using the type Number for the rating field instead of number.
The 'Number' type in TS is a wrapper object, not the primitive number type. The DecimalPipe cannot handle this wrapper type, hence the error.
To fix this, you can change the type of 'rating' in the RoomList interface from Number to number.Try this:
export interface RoomList {
roomNumber: number;
roomType: string;
amenities: string;
price: number;
photos: string;
checkinTime: Date;
checkoutTime: Date;
rating: number; // Change this line
}


Many thanks @Kevin. I got it
